# XGBoost Sagemaker model fits but won't predict

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

Using the Sagemaker built in xgboost model I am able to fit the model on the training and validation data, and successfully deploy it as an endpoint.

```
# Creating deployable object of the model
predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,
                            instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge',
                            endpoint_name = 'endpoint')

# Setup before predictions
predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer()

# Connecting to the endpoint previously deployed
endpoint_name = 'endpoint'
predictor = sagemaker.predictor.Predictor(endpoint_name = endpoint_name)

# Converting test file to be passed
arr_test = test.values
# arr_test = arr_test.tobytes()
print(arr_test)
```

When I go to call on this endpoint and use the `.predict()` method, I'm thrown the following error. [image: error] I have tried switching the input array to bytes, but am also getting another error when I do that (shown in the screenshot below). I am following an example from a Udemy course which uses the exact same method, but I am applying it to a personal dataset which was extracted from an RDS file, then converted into a dataframe and into a csv from that [image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to append the predict with a decode("utf-8") ?

eg:

result = predictor.predict(arr_test[:1]).decode("utf-8")

Please post back or vote if it fixes the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."